# If you released a book from the thermosphere or mesosphere would the book float slightly?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, atmospheric-science, fluid-statics

If you released a book from the thermosphere or mesosphere would the book float slightly?

Comment: Why would it float?

Comment: I'm assuming that it would float because you are further from Earth's surface compared to outer space where there is no gravity. If it wouldn't float I imagine that it would not fall at the same sped as other objects closer to Earth's surface.

Comment: It wouldn't have quite as high acceleration, but gravity is still quite strong there.  In space stations they only float due to the nature of orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are further from Earth's surface compared to outer space where
>   there is no gravity

You need to realise that the influence of the earth's gravity is **everywhere**. At no distance from the earth does its gravitation fall to zero. Remember that Newton's Theory of Gravitation says that $$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

This shows that the gravitational force between 2 bodies is proportional to their masses ($m_1$ and $m_2$) and inversely proportional to the square of the distance ($r$) between them. Hence, no matter how large $r$ gets, the force between 2 masses can never fall to $0$. It just gets weaker as you move further away. Hence, no matter how far away from the earth you are, the book will still be under the influence of earth's gravity.

There are couple of provisos though.

First, if you are in orbit around the earth then, while you are still falling down under the influence of earth's gravity, you are also moving horizontally at a speed large enough so you always fall past the horizon, and you never hit the earth. To understand this, imagine firing a cannonball horizontally. As you shoot it faster and faster, it will travel further and further until, when its speed is about $7.7km/s$ it travels so far that it goes right around the earth. Similarly, if you release your book while in orbit, it will stay there. To make it fall down you first need to reduce its horizontal speed - just like making the cannonball fly a bit slower.

Secondly, if you are far enough away from the earth, you have to start accounting for the gravity of other bodies like the moon, the sun, Jupiter, etc. Hence your fall may be deflected and you may even end up falling onto another body such as the sun.

There are many other complications to this such as the effect of atmospheric drag that will eventually slow you down and make you fall from orbit - even space is not completely empty. Einstein's relativity alters all this too, but only very minutely - unless you are moving at extremely high speeds (close to the speed of light). Under normal circumstances Newton's theory is more than accurate enough.

Comment: This totally makes sense to me.

Comment: This totally makes sense to me